# vuejs bind select values to class value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple select in vue2:

```
  <select v-model="formColumns">
    <option value="one_x">1</option>
    <option value="two_x">2</option>
    <option value="three_x">3</option>
  </select>
```

I'm then trying to apply the value of this, as a class:

I've tried this:

```
<div v:bind:class="formColumns"></div>
```

and this:

```
  <div v:bind:class="{one_x: formColumns === 'one_x'}" ></div>
```

Neither of these seem to work.  I have:

```
  data () {
    return {
     formColumns: 'one_x'
    }
  }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your v-bind directive syntax is not correct

```
<div v:bind:class="formColumns"></div>
```

Use this:

```
<div v-bind:class="formColumns"></div>
```

or this:

```
<div :class="formColumns"></div>
```